# Converter between PDB or mmCIF and MMTF

Tags: file-formats, pdb, 3d-structure

I'd like to test [MMTF](http://mmtf.rcsb.org), a new format for storing biomolecular structures which is promoted by RCSB as a more compact alternative to mmCIF and PDB.

From [MMTF FAQ](http://mmtf.rcsb.org/faq.html):

> - How do I convert a PDBx/mmCIF file to an MMTF file?
>
>   The BioJava library contains methods to read and write PDBx/mmCIF files and MMTF files.

Can I do such a conversion, ideally from command line, but without writing my own Java program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a very quick and dirty script to handle conversion between file types using BioJava.

https://github.com/eedlund/Utils/tree/master/BioUtils

Download the jar file [here](https://github.com/eedlund/Utils/raw/master/BioUtils/BioUtils.jar)

To run: `java -jar BioUtils.jar $FILE $TYPE`

where \$FILE is a PDB or mmCIF file you'd like to convert and \$TYPE is the format of the output file [PDB, CIF, MMTF].

Comment: Does this take into account biological assemblies, or simply convert e.g. MMTF to a PDB of the asymmetric unit?

Answer (score 2):

You looked at this https://github.com/rcsb/mmtf-python

"The python implementation of the MMTF API, decoder and encoder."

Comment: but how to use it to convert between MMTF and something else?

Comment: There's also a C++ encoder/decoder available here: https://github.com/rcsb/mmtf-cpp

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [BioStructures.jl](https://github.com/BioJulia/BioStructures.jl) in Julia. All the 6 transformations between PDB/mmCIF/MMTF are possible.

For example, PDB to MMTF:

```
using BioStructures
struc = read(in_filepath, PDB)
writemmtf(out_filepath, struc)
```

mmCIF to MMTF:

```
using BioStructures
struc = read(in_filepath, MMCIF)
writemmtf(out_filepath, struc)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PyMol to change the PDB to mmtf or other format. First open the PDB file and then choose file->export molecule-> choose which format you want to save as

Answer (score 1):

This [python script](https://gist.github.com/sbliven/b7cc2c5305aa3652a75a580ae7c6ce33) uses [Biopython](https://biopython.org/) and does the job well even on large structures. For example:

`python cif2pdb.py 4ckh-assembly-1.cif 4ckh-assembly-1.pdb`

This generates the structure below.

[image: A large protein structure]

Comment: The question was about converting to/from MMTF.
For PDB <-> mmCIF there are too many tools to list them all. For example, I'm maintaining [gemmi](https://github.com/project-gemmi/gemmi) which should be at least an order of magnitude [faster](https://github.com/project-gemmi/mmcif-benchmark) than BioPython and it also converts more fields (but I'm obviously biased).

Comment: @marcin Thanks for the heads up. Since this is probably a more common conversion, I've opened a new [question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/10896/how-to-quickly-and-robustly-convert-between-mmcif-and-pdb).